# PHP preg_replace и windows-1251 (символы Ч и Ё)

Tags: pcre, php

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Столкнулся с непонятным поведением preg_replace в PHP:

PHP файл в utf-8:

```
<?php
header ( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
setlocale ( LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8' );
echo '"' . preg_replace ( '/[^\p{L}\d]/iu', ' ', 'ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю1234567890' ) . '"';
//результат: "ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю1234567890"
```

Результат предсказуемый (все символы на месте).

PHP файл в ansi:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.cp1251');
echo '"' . preg_replace ( '/[^\p{L}\d]/i', ' ', 'ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю1234567890' ) . '"';
//результат: " йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэя смитьбю1234567890"
```

Т.е. не хватает "ё" и "ч". Не подскажите, в чём может быть причина и в какую сторону копать?

PHP Version 5.4.21

[PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php) Library Version: 8.32 2012-11-30

Благодарю за внимание.

С уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на [поверхности](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php) (в документации, по ссылка в вопросе).

\p{L} - это для Unicode.

\w - для однобайтной кодировки.