# PHP mb_stripos и windows-1251 (заглавные символы Ч и Ё)

Tags: php

Был похожий вопрос [PHP preg_replace и windows-1251 (символы Ч и Ё)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269041/php-preg-replace-%D0%B8-windows-1251-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%A7-%D0%B8-%D0%81)

Но мой несколько в другом
В кодировке windows-1251 не находятся заглавные символы Ч и Ё, если в запросе поиска маленькие буквы - ч и ё, несмотря на игнорирование регистра,
например

```
<?
$findme1    = 'ч';
$findme2    = 'ё';
$findme3    = 'Ч';
$findme4    = 'Ё';
$findme5    = 'у';
$findme6    = 'У';
$mystring1 = 'СУТОЧНОЁ';
$pos1 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme1);
$pos2 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme2);
$pos3 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme3);
$pos4 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme4);
$pos5 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme5);
$pos6 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme6);
echo "ч - $pos1, ё - $pos2, Ч - $pos3, Ё - $pos4, у - $pos5, У - $pos6";
?>
соответственно выводит ч - , ё - , Ч - 4, Ё - 7, у - 1, У - 1
```

PHP Version 5.2.12

PCRE Library Version    7.9 2009-04-11

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Известный факт что начиная с 5.6 с этим проще

в конце концов обошел вопрос сбоку

```
//предварительно прописываем локали
$locales = array("Russian_Russia.1251",
                "ru_RU.CP1251",
                "ru_RU.cp1251",
                "ru_RU",
                "RU",
                "rus_RUS.1251");
if (false === setlocale(LC_ALL, $locales)) {
// failed to set locale
}

$findme1    = 'ч';
$findme2    = 'ё';
$findme3    = 'Ч';
$findme4    = 'Ё';
$findme5    = 'у';
$findme6    = 'У';
$mystring1 = 'СУТОЧНОЁ';
$pos1 = mb_stripos(strtolower($mystring1), strtolower($findme1));
$pos2 = mb_stripos(strtolower($mystring1), strtolower($findme2));
$pos3 = mb_stripos(strtolower($mystring1), strtolower($findme3));
$pos4 = mb_stripos(strtolower($mystring1), strtolower($findme4));
$pos5 = mb_stripos(strtolower($mystring1), strtolower($findme5));
$pos6 = mb_stripos(strtolower($mystring1), strtolower($findme6));
echo "ч - $pos1, ё - $pos2, Ч - $pos3, Ё - $pos4, у - $pos5, У - $pos6";
```

выводит соответственно

ч - 4, ё - 7, Ч - 4, Ё - 7, у - 1, У - 1

Answer (score 0):

Тест (PHP Version 5.6.8):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="Windows-1251">
<title>чё-ЧЁ?</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$findme1    = 'ч';
$findme2    = 'Ч';
$findme3    = 'ё';
$findme4    = 'Ё';
$findme5    = 'у';
$findme6    = 'У';
$mystring1 = 'СУТОЧНОЁ';
$pos1 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme1);
$pos2 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme2);
$pos3 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme3);
$pos4 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme4);
$pos5 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme5);
$pos6 = mb_stripos($mystring1, $findme6);
echo "ч - $pos1, Ч - $pos2, ё - $pos3, Ё - $pos4, у - $pos5, У - $pos6";

foreach (array('СУТОЧНОЁ', 'суточноё') as $mystring){
    print("<br><br>mystring = '$mystring'");
    $mystring_UTF16 = mb_convert_encoding($mystring, "UTF-16");
    $mystring_CP1251 = mb_convert_encoding($mystring, "CP1251");
    $find = array("Ч", "ч", "Ё", "ё", "У", "у");

    foreach($find as $f){
        $f_UTF16 = mb_convert_encoding($f, "UTF-16");
        $f_CP1251 = mb_convert_encoding($f, "CP1251");
        printf("<br>%s (UTF-16) - %02d(mb_stripos) : %02d(stripos) &emsp; %s (CP1251) - %02d(mb_stripos) : %02d(stripos)",   
            $f, mb_stripos($mystring_UTF16, $f_UTF16), stripos($mystring_UTF16, $f_UTF16),
            $f, mb_stripos($mystring_CP1251, $f_CP1251), stripos($mystring_CP1251, $f_CP1251) );
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Результаты:

```
ч - 4, Ч - 4, ё - 7, Ё - 7, у - 1, У - 1

mystring = 'СУТОЧНОЁ'
Ч (UTF-16) - 08(mb_stripos) : 08(stripos)   Ч (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 04(stripos)
ч (UTF-16) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)   ч (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)
Ё (UTF-16) - 14(mb_stripos) : 14(stripos)   Ё (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 07(stripos)
ё (UTF-16) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)   ё (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)
У (UTF-16) - 02(mb_stripos) : 02(stripos)   У (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 01(stripos)
у (UTF-16) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)   у (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)

mystring = 'суточноё'
Ч (UTF-16) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)   Ч (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)
ч (UTF-16) - 08(mb_stripos) : 08(stripos)   ч (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 04(stripos)
Ё (UTF-16) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)   Ё (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)
ё (UTF-16) - 14(mb_stripos) : 14(stripos)   ё (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 07(stripos)
У (UTF-16) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)   У (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 00(stripos)
у (UTF-16) - 02(mb_stripos) : 02(stripos)   у (CP1251) - 00(mb_stripos) : 01(stripos)
```

То есть в более новой версии буквы "ч/Ч", "ё/Ё", "у/У" обрабатываются одинаково, но тем не менее:

1. `mb_stripos` не работает с однобайтовыми кодировками кириллицы.
2. `mb_stripos` и `stripos` чувствительны к регистру кириллицы.